# Prove that $1/||S^{-1}||\leq ||S-T||$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $||\cdot||$ denote the operator norm, with $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $S\in GL(n)$, and suppose that $T(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$. On one hand, we have that $$||S(\mathbf{x})||=||{S(\mathbf{x})-T(\mathbf{x})}||=||{(S-T)(\mathbf{x})}||\leq ||{S-T}||||{\mathbf{x}}||.$$ So, I need something like $$||\mathbf{x}||/||S^{-1}||\leq ||S(\mathbf{x})||$$ to obtain the result I want. I know that $1/||S^{-1}||\leq||S||$, but I don't see exactly how to use it.

EDIT: $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}.$

Comment: What other information would you like? That's all that I can think of except that $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ we have

$$||x||=||S^{-1}(S(x))|| \le ||S^{-1}||*||S(x)||.$$

This gives

$$\frac{||x||}{||S^{-1}||} \le ||S(x)||.$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Fred.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x \neq 0$ we can estimate 
$$
\Vert x \Vert = \Vert S^{-1} Sx - S^{-1} Tx \Vert  = \Vert S^{-1}(S-T)x \Vert \le \Vert S^{-1} \Vert \Vert S-T \Vert \Vert x \Vert.
$$
Divide both sides by $\Vert S^{-1} \Vert \Vert x \Vert$ and we get
$$
\frac{1}{\Vert S^{-1} \Vert} \le \Vert S-T \Vert.
$$

Comment: Nice! That is simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Your result is not true, since $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert S^{-1} Sx - S^{-1} Tx \Vert  = \Vert S^{-1}(S-T)x \Vert \le \Vert S^{-1} \Vert \Vert S-T \Vert \Vert x \Vert$ only holds if $Tx=0$, and not for all $x \ne 0$

Comment: @Fred Yes it is.  The first liine in OP's post says "and suppose that $T(x)=0$".  My argument is not for general $x$, but rather the specific $x$ mentioned in the hypotheses.

Comment: @Glitch: yes you are right.  I apologize